# Gazebo, pioneer model and plugins

Tags: ros, gazebo, path-planning, gazebo-plugins, pioneer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm porting a pioneerAT gazebo model on urdf model for ros.
What I should do is loading that urdf model on gazebo (ros version) and after move the robot programmatically (I have to test my own path planner).
What is the best way for do that, maybe use plugins?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11722/gazebo,-pioneer-model-and-plugins/) by [Nikkio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1291/nikkio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-10-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/StartingGazebo) is an introduction to using Gazebo with ROS commands.

[Here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials) are some tutorials for using urdf with ROS. You should definitely look at the tutorial for "Building a Movable Robot Model with URDF".

Finally, you could also look at the [guardian stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/Guardian) to see how to properly manipulate a four-wheel skid steer robot like the pioneer2AT.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1